Is there a way to create a context menu item that only appears when the cursor is focus on certain words for a vscode language server extension?
Currently, I am attempting to create a language server for generating and saving an image from a custom language (similar to plantUML). I want to be able to define multiple diagrams in one file, and as such I was wondering if it is possible for a vscode language server extension to make a context menu item appear only when the cursor is focused on the name of the diagram.
I believe this would have to performed with a custom when clause, however this must be done client-side, and I cannot figure out if there is some way for me to force the client to perform this check every time the cursor is moved. Currently, I have only figured out how to detect the cursor location on activation.
I have also thought about using one of the current requests sent to the language server (such as  go to definition), and using this instead to run my command, however I would prefer to add my own context menu item if possible.
Is there a way for me to get the client to check the cursor location every time it is moved, so that I can use this to update a when clause? Or is there a different workaround so that I can get the context menu item to appear only on certain words?
my menu contribution to the package.json

my current activate function

Many thanks for any help/ideas, and please let me know if I can provide further explanation.

you can use the hover provider to get a call back when the cursor is stationary over a particular place, process the location context, set you context variable and return an empty result of the callback
